# SQL Query XML Column using XML tag?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, xml-parsing

I have a table with some various information in the columns. One column named `CorrelationInfo` is XML and appears as follows:

```
<Backlog xmlns:xsi = yadda yadda yadda>
    <Correlations>
      <MemCorrelation EID = "1234">
      </MemCorrelation>
    </Correlations>
</Backlog>
```

I need a query that will count the number of rows where `EID = "1234"`.

**Please note:** The more efficient the query the better. There are thousands of rows to query against.

I have tried something myself but I am still learning. Here is my work:

```sql
Declare @myEID varchar(MAX)
SET @myID = "1234"

SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.CorrelationInfo.exist('/Backlog/Correlations/MemCorrelation[text()= @myID') =1
```

I have some experience querying XML but never when the where condition is located in an XML tag like `MemCorrelation EID = "1234"`...

This is for SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like that:

```
    DECLARE @myID  int = 1234;
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM TABLE t
    WHERE t.CorrelationInfo.exist('/Backlog/Correlations/MemCorrelation[@EID=sql:variable("@myID")]') = 1
```

Exists will return `1` if there is an element MemCorrelation with an attribute EID with value equal to that of the sql variable @myID.

In order to increase performance I would suggest to create at least a Primary XML index on the table and to experiment with a secondary one.

References for further reading:

[sql:variable() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx)

[predicates in path expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177470.aspx)

[XML Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx)